# Whats the best to way convert a set of Java objects to another set of objects?

Tags: java, collections, casting, set

Basic Java question here from a real newbie.  I have a set of Java objects (of class "MyClass") that implement a certain interface (Interface "MyIfc").  I have a set of these objects stored in a private variable in my class that is declared as follows:

```
protected Set<MyClass> stuff = new HashSet<MyClass>();
```

I need to provide a public method that returns this set as a collection of objects of type "MyIfc".

```
public Collection<MyIfc> getMyStuff() {...}
```

How do I do the conversion?  The following line gives me an error that it can't do the conversion.  I would have guessed the compiler knew that objects of class MyClass implemented MyIfc and therefore would have handled it.

```
Collection<MyIfc> newstuff = stuff;
```

Any enlightenment is appreciated.

Comment: How about returning `Collection<? extends Mylfc>`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the most correct way is:

```
    return new HashSet<MyIfc>(stuff);
```

If the class is too large to do that, you can do:

```
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(stuff);
```

Comment: This has the same benefits as Nathan's approach above, but does it in one line via the constructor as opposed to calling "addAll".  For that reason I think this is the best answer.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler doesn't like your assignment of stuff to newstuff, because it lays open the possibility of putting things in newstuff that implement MyIfc but are not of type MyClass. You could have your getter create its own collection:

```
public Collection<MyIfc> getMyStuff() {
    Collection<MyIfc> coll = new HashSet<MyIfc>();
    coll.addAll(myStuff);
    return coll;
}
```

Comment: I like this approach because I get to keep the collection of MyClass -- in this case I need to work with them as MyClass sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any conversion. You will have to type your `stuff` as `Set<MyIfc>`.

Background: Yes, it is correct that if you have an object of type `MyClass` this will also be usable as a `MyIfc` instance. But you explicitly typed your Set as of type `MyClass`. And this is simply something different than a Set of type `MyIfc`. After all, you could also have other classes that implement `MyIfc`and then you could also put them into your `Set<MyIfc>` but not into `Set<MyClass>`.

Comment: This would be a great idea if I were able to not treat the members of the HashSet as MyClass.  However, in my case I need to do that, so I prefer to leave the internal collection as it is.

Answer (score 0):

[Google collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) define a bunch of lazy adapters, that may be suitable for your purposes.

One in particular is [Collections2.transform](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Collections2.html#transform(java.util.Collection,%20com.google.common.base.Function)). Here is an example on how to adapt your collection:

```
Collection<MyIfc> newStuff =
  Collections2.transform(
    stuff,
    new Function<MyClass, MyIfc>( )
    {
      public MyIfc apply ( final MyClass from )
      {
        return (MyIfc) from; // This may throw a ClassCastException though
      }
    }
  )
```

Comment: Seems like a very strange use of transform to me. Why not use stuff as a `Set<MyIfc>` internally. And beweare your code will return a live view which does *not* allow add/addAll.

Comment: I agree, it doesn't make sense to do all this.