# Cast Set subclass to Set superclass java

Tags: java, generics, casting, set

is there any way to cast `Set<Subclass>` to `Set<Superclass>` ?

I have tried this 3 ways bellow? is there a better way or some best practice for this?

```
// class extends superclass
final class MapEntryCustom implements Map.Entry<String,Object> {
        // all implementation
}

// var to be casted
private Set<MapEntryCustom> entrySet = new HashSet<>();

// 3 trying way of casting
public Set<Entry<String, Object>> getSetMapEntry() {
   
   return (Set<Entry<String, Object>>) entrySet; // error cannot cast
   
   return (Set<? extends Entry<String, Object>>) entrySet; // error cannot cast
   
   return (Set<Entry<String, Object>>) (Set<? extends Entry<String, Object>>) entrySet; // warning type safe

}
```

Comment: could you tell, why you want to do this? Is it just out of curiosity or something you want to achieve - i.e. is there some way of assigning or using the result of your method?

Comment: You can't safely cast: a set of subclass is not a set of superclass: you can add an instance of superclass to the latter, which also adds to the former (since they are the same set), but now not everything in the former is an instance of subclass. The only entirely safe thing to do is to create a new set using the copy constructor.

Comment: @juwil I'm trying to create a map implementation on AbstractMap just for studying and I have falled in this stuff. So AbstractMap contains an abstract method that return this set and I need to return my implementation of set entry

Comment: [Try returning it as a new set.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745899/whats-the-best-to-way-convert-a-set-of-java-objects-to-another-set-of-objects)

Comment: In short the best way is creating a new instance of object with constructor or addAll method. Is it right?

Comment: it still depends.. the most useful way would be, to simply change the signature of your method getSetMapEntry and then return your set without any cast:     public Set<? extends Map.Entry<String, Object>> getSetMapEntry() {
        return entrySet;}